# numpy, different slices for different layers of array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have 3d array `m*n*k` and for every 2d-layer I want to take a subarray of size `i*j`. I have an array c with size `2*k` of coordinates of starts of slices for every layer. Is there nice and easy way to get what I need without any loops?

Example:

```
test = np.arange(18).reshape((3,3,2))
c = np.array([[0,1], [0, 1]])

test[:,:,0] = array([[ 0,  2,  4],
                     [ 6,  8, 10],
                     [12, 14, 16]])

test[:,:,1] = array([[ 1,  3,  5],
                     [ 7,  9, 11],
                     [13, 15, 17]])
```

I want to get an array

```
  [[[ 0,  9],
    [ 2,  11]],

   [[ 6,  15],
    [ 8,  17]]]
```

Solution with loop:

```
h=2
w=2
layers = 2
F = np.zeros((h,w,layers))
for k in range(layers):
    F[:,:,k] = test[c[0,k]:c[0,k]+h, c[1,k]:c[1,k]+w, k]
```

Comment: Could you share how you would implement that with loops, as it's not clear on getting to the expected o/p from the given inputs?

Comment: added solution with loop

Comment: When I run the code on the given inputs, I see `IndexError`.

Comment: Oops. Fixed that, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach making use of [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
d0,d1,d2 = np.ogrid[:h,:w,:layers]
out = test[d0+c[0],d1+c[1],d2]
```

Sample run -

```
In [112]: test = np.arange(200).reshape((10,10,2))
     ...: c = np.array([[0,1], [0, 1]])
     ...: 

In [113]: h=4
     ...: w=5
     ...: layers = 2
     ...: F = np.zeros((h,w,layers))
     ...: for k in range(layers):
     ...:     F[:,:,k] = test[c[0,k]:c[0,k]+h, c[1,k]:c[1,k]+w, k]
     ...:     

In [114]: d0,d1,d2 = np.ogrid[:h,:w,:layers]
     ...: out = test[d0+c[0],d1+c[1],d2]
     ...: 

In [115]: np.allclose(F, out)
Out[115]: True
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when h != w. I'm getting `Index error: shape mismatch`

Comment: @EgorIgnatenkov Was a bug indeed. Updated. Check it out.